# Loops in data using str_replace_all and strsplit in R

Tags: r, string, loops, replace, strsplit

I have a dataframe with a column with the next caracteres:

```
 head(example)
  X.       S10   tactagcaatacgcttgcgttcggtggttaagtatgtataatgcgcgggcttgtcgt
1  +      AM \t\ttgctatcctgacagttgtcacgctgattggtgtcgttacaatctaacgcatcgccaa
2  +      AR \t\tgtactagagaactagtgcattagcttatttttttgttatcatgctaaccacccggcg
3  +     DE  \taattgtgatgtgtatcgaagtgtgttgcggagtagatgttagaatactaacaaactc
```

```
So I want replace each letter by specific chain. For example: when it appears "a" i want put 0,0,0,1. But I get it
```

str_replace_all(example, "[a]", c("0","0","0","1"))
[1] "tgct0tcctg0c0gttgtc0cgctg0ttggtgtcgtt0c00tct00cgc0tcgcc00"

```
Also I need separate each value in one column.
```

Comment: Do you need `str_replace_all(example, "a", '0001')`

Comment: Yes, exactly and t character replace for "1000"

Comment: Are those columns 'S10', 'AM', 'AR', 'DE'

Comment: No, the column is  tactagcaatacgcttgcgttcggtggttaagtatgtataatgcgcgggcttgtcg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a named vector with `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(example, setNames( c('0001', '1000'), c('a', 't')))
```

It replaces the lettters 'a', 't' with the values '0001' and '1000' respectively

Comment: It's works, but how can I make the loops of the column in the dataframe??

Comment: @RaqS. You don't need any loop as the function is vectorized i.e. `str_replace_all(df1$col, setNames( c('0001', '1000'), c('a', 't'))) `

Comment: In this case is a vector but I extract of my dataframe. I edit my question

Comment: @RaqS Can you use `dput` to update the post as it is not clear whether your data are in columns or in rows

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have a column and I need change making loops with the rows of the columns but I began with simple example in format vector

Comment: @RaqS when you apply this code `str_replace_all(df1$col, setNames( c('0001', '1000'), c('a', 't')))` what is the issue you got

Comment: Perfect its world @akrun